# Solve Mysql Spatial error

Tags: geoserver, spatial-database, mysql

Converting shp2mysql will leads an null value in geom filed.  how to rectify the the problem.

```
shp2mysql -s 32643 landuse landuse LIS >landuse.sql
```

Comment: Is there any any type of data in shape file (like point,line & polygon etc) ? plus did you try with another shape file + check out details https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/MySQL

Comment: yes, ofcource all the point files and polygon files are generating values correct. but the landless layer getting an error.